# Rails TypeError in SurveysController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having problems with something very simple, that i can't quite figure out why it isn't working.

Supposed:

Resources

- Survey
- Year
- User

Also,

- survey belongs_to :year
- survey belongs_to :user

When i try to create a new survey, if I only keep the user relation it works. But if I include both relations, then it fails with

```
TypeError in SurveysController#create
Cannot visit Year
```

I can't figure this out... Any tips?

Comment: Could you post the code of your models and the create action? It's hard to say without these information.

Comment: Figured it out. I had uniqueness validation on the Survey, checking it to be no more than 1 survey per year, but had "year" on the uniqueness instead of "year_id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had model validation in place which wasn't right.

```
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :year, :message => "apenas um registo por ano"}
```

Of course this was wrong, i should have used

```
:scope => :year_id
```

I had been using a collection for the years but turned it into a resource and forgot to check the validation.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from you success.  Cheers~